# Acumatica - Graph extension and Screen Renaming

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Good day!

I have extended a graph to change the screen title of an existing page.

```
public class NonStockItemMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<NonStockItemMaint>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        PXSiteMap.CurrentNode.Title = "My Custom Page Title";
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the method seems not to be working.

I also tried creating a new page for that existing graph, so that I will have the control to name the page, but as i clicked the newly created link, I am being redirected to the original page of the graph, and so the page title is still the same.

Is there any ways for me to properly rename my page?

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to chance the name in the sitemap directly? Creating a graph extension is not a new page so it would use the name of the base graph you are extending. If you want a new page you need to create a new aspx page and a new graph (public class MyNewGraph : NonStockItemMaint for example)

Comment: Hello @Brendan, Does this violate the ISV standards? I tried creating the page using the same method that you mentioned and it it solved the renaming issue. The problem is, there are certain methods of the inherited graph that are not present on  the new page.

Comment: I think it depends on what you are doing. If you are trying to create a new page that works like non stock item I dont see why it wouldn't work or be a valid solution. What calls are you missing for your new page?

Comment: It is as Brendan says, the Title used is the one from the sitemap. You need to create a new sitemap entry. Don't change the name of the original page or sitemap entry, base product features should not be hidden by configuration.

Comment: Hello @Brendan, Thanks for the suggestion, I managed to rename the page through inheritance. And the methods that are not present, are on the apsx.cs side. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Hello @HB_ACUMATICA, Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem through inheritance. I also checked the aspx.cs file of the page to make sure that everything is running correctly. Thanks for all the help.